# SQL Matching up Values in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server.

I have a row that contains a users USERID and also their Paypal Account Number. Sometimes people manually input their USERID as the Paypal Account Number. I need to do a query to find all people with userid = PaypalID. The paypal id is a varchar and userid is an int.

I've already tried

```
  SELECT *

  FROM [Users] WHERE userID = paypalid
```

and I get the error
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The conversion of the varchar value '530817015001' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT *

  FROM [Users] WHERE cast(userID as varchar) = cast(paypalid as varchar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the `int` to a `varchar`

```
SELECT *
FROM [Users] WHERE CAST(userID AS VARCHAR(50)) = paypalid
```